# Interesting sites without pull-backs

Tags: sheaf-theory, grothendieck-topologies

I've seen at least a couple of sources (e.g. the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coverage)) that do not require the covering families in a coverage to be closed under pull-backs.  The question is simple:  ***are there any interesting examples that justify such generality?***

**Elaboration**

Of course, nothing is wrong with greater generality per se, but in this case, it seems as if the greater generality comes at a cost.  Perhaps most obvious is that it makes the definition of a coverage more complicated:

> A *coverage* on a category is an assignment to each object $U$ a collection of precovers, called the *covers* of $U$, that has the property that, for every cover of an object $U$ and map from $V$ to $U$ there is a cover of $V$ that has the property that every element in the cover of $V$ composed with the map into $U$ factors through an element in the cover of $U$.

in contrast to

> A *coverage* is an assignment to each object $U$ a collection of precovers, the *covers* of $U$, that has the property that a pull-back of a cover is a cover.

(Here, the term *precover* on $U$ means just a collection of maps with codomain $U$.)

Arguably more significant is that, if our coverage is not closed under pull-backs, then the usual "equalizer definition" of sheaves no longer makes sense.  Instead, one must phrase things in terms of compatible collections of sections.  This, however, has the unfortunate property that it does not make sense for any codomain category whose objects don't have underlying sets.  On the other hand, using the "equalizer definition", we can define sheaves $\mathcal{O}\colon (\mathbf{X},\widetilde{\mathcal{U}})\rightarrow \mathbf{S}$ for *any* category $\mathbf{S}$:  in this sense, it seems as if in asking for greater generality for sites we have lost greater generality for sheaves.

Thus, if one really insists upon allowing coverages not closed under pull-backs, this suggests another question:  ***in this more general context, is there a convenient way to rephrase the sheaf axiom so as to make sense for arbitrary codomain category?***

Comment: You can take the closure of any site under pullbacks once you embed it into its topos of sheaves of sets.  The resulting site is (essentially) small if the original site is, contains the original site as a dense subsite, has the same category of sheaves, and is closed under pullbacks.  So you can always ensure the existence of pullbacks without changing anything.

Comment: That being said, the category of smooth manifolds and (arbitrary) smooth maps, equipped with the standard Grothendieck topology of open covers is a typical example of a site that does not admit pullbacks.

Comment: Also, you don't need pullbacks in order to use the usual definition of a sheaf: it suffices to show that pullbacks (i.e., base changes) of covering families exists and are covering families.  This is satisfied for many categories without pullbacks, e.g., for the site of smooth manifolds mentioned above.

Comment: "Also, you don't need pullbacks in order to use the usual definition of a sheaf: it suffices to show that pullbacks (i.e., base changes) of covering families exists and are covering families. " ---- That's a good point.  This is what I *actually* had in mind when writing the question, though I carelessly stated it in terms of the category itself having pull-backs.  I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Sheaves can be defined in this context for arbitrary target categories
as follows: a presheaf F is a sheaf if for any X and any covering family {U_i→X}
the canonical diagram F(X)→∏_iF(U_i)⇉∏_{V,g:V→U_i,h:V→U_j,f_ig=f_jh}F(V) is an equalizer diagram.
(By the way, this definition is closely related to hypercovers.)